# Select values of a column into one row - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to select in one row the value of a column that appears in multiple rows, I have the table `Solution`:

```
| StudentID | SolutionDate | SolutionTime | SongID |
----------------------------------------------------
|  0824616  | 2015-09-20   | 00:07:00     |   01   |
|  0824616  | 2015-09-20   | 00:05:00     |   02   |
|  0824616  | 2015-09-21   | 00:07:40     |   01   |
|  0824616  | 2015-09-21   | 00:10:00     |   03   |
|  0824616  | 2015-09-23   | 00:04:30     |   03   |
|  0824616  | 2015-09-23   | 00:11:30     |   03   |
```

I want to group the records by `StudentID` and `SongID`.

The expected output is:

```
| StudentID | SongID |  TimeA   |  TimeB   |  TimeC   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 0824616   |   01   | 00:07:00 | 00:07:40 |  NULL    |
| 0824616   |   02   | 00:05:00 |  NULL    |  NULL    |
| 0824616   |   03   | 00:10:00 | 00:04:30 | 00:11:30 |
```

There are 3 records by `StudentID-SongID` at the most. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: and... what have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with window function first to number the rows and then use conditional aggregation:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by studentid, songid 
                        order by solutiondate, solutiontime) rn from tablename)

select studentid,
       songid,
       max(case when rn = 1 then solutiontime end) as timea,
       max(case when rn = 2 then solutiontime end) as timeb,
       max(case when rn = 3 then solutiontime end) as timec
from cte
group by studentid, songid
```

Comment: I was trying with PIVOT or subselects but your solution worked for me Giorgí